# Easy Javascript div selection for a Novice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit of a JS novice so I am hoping this is an easy one for the experts. I have a script that currently pulls any div with a class that matches a single checked radio button. I would like to change the code so that the script pulls the divs with any class from multiple checked radio boxes. So for example if I have two radio buttons checked I only want to see the divs that have both classes. Here is the current setup:

The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.tags').find('input:radio').live('click', function () {
        $('.results > li').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
    <div class="tags">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="boys" />Boys
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="girls" />Girls
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="allgenders" checked />All
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="style" rel="vintage" />Vintage
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="style" rel="simple" />Simple
        </label>
    </div>
    <ul id="cardsWrapper" class="results">
        <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders simple">
            girls allgenders simple
        </li>
        <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders vintage">
            boys allgenders vintage
        </li>
        <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders vintage">
            girls allgenders vintage
        </li>
        <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders simple">
            boys allgenders simple
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But this only selects  with the class from the "gender" named radio buttons

Thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in version 1.6 and entirely removed in 1.9; is there a reason for using this (relatively) antiquated version of the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got some nice suggestions, I just add the following approach to show yet another approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.tags').find('input:radio[name="gender"], input:radio[name="style"]').on('click', function () {
        $('#cardsWrapper li').hide();
        gender = $('input:radio[name="gender"]:checked').attr("rel");
        style = $('input:radio[name="style"]:checked').attr("rel");
        $('#cardsWrapper li' + (gender ? ('.' + gender) : '') + (style ? ('.' + style) : '')).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, on the assumption that you can switch to the use of `on()`, in place of `live()`:

```
// select those <input> elements with a 'rel' attribute,
// and assign a change-event handler:
$('input[rel]').on('change', function() {
  // iterate over the checked <input> elements within the
  // .tags element(s), and create a map containing the
  // value of their 'rel' attribute:
  var classes = $('.tags input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('rel');
  // using get() to create an array from the map:
  }).get();

  // hiding all the <li> elements within the #cardsWrapper element,
  // then filtering those <li> elements:
  $('#cardsWrapper li').hide().filter(function() {
    // keeping only those elements for whom the following
    // assessment returns true,
    // checking, using is(), that the current element has
    // all the required classes:
    return $(this).is('.' + classes.join('.'));
  // if it does, it's kept in the collection (otherwise discared)
  // and then shown:
  }).show();
// triggering the change event, to fire the change-handler (above)
// on page-load/DOM-ready:
}).change();
```

```js
$('input[rel]').on('change', function() {
  var classes = $('.tags input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('rel');
  }).get();
  $('#cardsWrapper li').hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).is('.' + classes.join('.'));
  }).show();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="boys" />Boys
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="girls" />Girls
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="allgenders" checked />All
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="vintage" />Vintage
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="simple" />Simple
  </label>
</div>
<ul id="cardsWrapper" class="results">
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders simple">
    girls allgenders simple
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders vintage">
    boys allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders vintage">
    girls allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders simple">
    boys allgenders simple
  </li>
</ul>
```

And, in plain JavaScript:

```
// creating a named function to handle the change event:
function showAppropriate() {
  // 'this' is passed in via the use of addEventListener()
  // later, and refers to the <div class="tags"> node.

  // using querySelectorAll() to find all checked <input>
  // elements with 'rel' attribute within 'this':
  var checked = this.querySelectorAll('input[rel]:checked'),
    // using Array.prototype.map(), along with
    // Function.prototype.call(), to create an array of
    // the checked <input>s' 'rel' attribute-values:
    classes = Array.prototype.map.call(checked, function(input) {
      return input.getAttribute('rel');
    }),
    // finding the element containing the <li> elements:
    list = document.querySelector('#cardsWrapper'),

    // finding all the <li> elements within that element:
    hide = list.querySelectorAll('li'),

    // finding all <li> elements with the required classes,
    // by converting the array of class-names to a string,
    // joining the array together with '.' characters:
    show = list.querySelectorAll('li.' + classes.join('.'));

  // using Array.prototype.forEach(), and Function.prototype.call(),
  // to iterate over all <li> elements to hide them:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(hide, function(li) {
    li.style.display = 'none';
  });

  // as above, but showing these elements:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(show, function(li) {
    li.style.display = 'list-item';
  });
}

var selection = document.querySelector('.tags');

selection.addEventListener('change', showAppropriate);
```

```js
function showAppropriate() {
  var checked = this.querySelectorAll('input[rel]:checked'),
    classes = Array.prototype.map.call(checked, function(input) {
      return input.getAttribute('rel');
    }),
    list = document.querySelector('#cardsWrapper'),
    hide = list.querySelectorAll('li'),
    show = list.querySelectorAll('li.' + classes.join('.'));

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(hide, function(li) {
    li.style.display = 'none';
  });
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(show, function(li) {
    li.style.display = 'list-item';
  });
}

var selection = document.querySelector('.tags');

selection.addEventListener('change', showAppropriate);
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="boys" />Boys
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="girls" />Girls
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="allgenders" checked />All
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="vintage" />Vintage
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="simple" />Simple
  </label>
</div>
<ul id="cardsWrapper" class="results">
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders simple">
    girls allgenders simple
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders vintage">
    boys allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders vintage">
    girls allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders simple">
    boys allgenders simple
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [`:checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 0):

The code gets a little more complicated, but it can be done. You just need to get the checked value of each input and go from there:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  // Step 1: Get all of the checked inputs.
  var inputs = $('input[type=radio]:checked');

  // Step 2: Get all of the list items and reset their visibility.
  var lis = $('#cardsWrapper li');
  lis.show();
  
  // Step 3: For each checked input, get the rel. If it's valid,
  //         hide the non-matching elements.
  inputs.each(function(i, e) {
    var value = $(e).attr('rel');
    if(value) lis.not('.' + value).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="boys" />Boys
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="girls" />Girls
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" rel="allgenders" checked />All
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="vintage" />Vintage
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="style" rel="simple" />Simple
  </label>
</div>
<ul id="cardsWrapper" class="results">
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders simple">
    girls allgenders simple
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders vintage">
    boys allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper girls allgenders vintage">
    girls allgenders vintage
  </li>
  <li class="cardsearchWrapper boys allgenders simple">
    boys allgenders simple
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the code is doing when changing one of the radio buttons:

1. hiding all li elements
2. showing all of the matching gender elements (regardless of style)
3. showing all of the matching style elements

You are not 'hiding' the unmatched style elements in step 3 that were shown in step 2.

Perhaps try reversing the logic:

1. show all of the li elements
2. hide all of the not matching gender elements
3. hide all of the not matching style elements.